# get_post_meta not working but meta value is available in database

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on programmatically add product (WooCommerce) function but couldn't get correct result,  returns empty array.

```
<?php 
$downloadable_files = get_post_meta(417,'_downloadable_files');
print_r($downloadable_files);
?>
```

`wp_postmeta` table view:

[image]

Full row view:

[image]

Code to add downloadable_files:

```
<?php 
$files = array();
$file_name = wc_clean("MP15");
$file_url = "http://localhost/wp/directory/locations/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/YouTubeLogo.png";
$file_hash = md5($file_url);
$files[$file_hash] = array('name' => $file_name,'file' => $file_url);
update_post_meta(417, '_downloadable_files', $files );
?>
```

What am I missing? Also I check when I add same product in admin it is working perfectly, but through programmatically I am facing only this issue.

Comment: what is the result of `print_r($downloadable_files);` ?

Comment: only this : Array ( ) , empty array ,